# How to redeploy war file in tomcat without deleting/undeploy the old application?

Tags: java, tomcat

I already have a working Tomcat Server with Web Manager where I can deploy my WAR file.

The WAR file contains my web application and this web application has a feature where user can upload images into one of it's folder.

The problem is when I need to update the web application using a new WAR file.

When I upload it through Tomcat manager. It says WAR file already exist.
I have to UNDEPLOY it first before I can upload the updated WAR.

I don't want to do this UNDEPLOY process because it will delete the application along with all the images that user already uploaded.

So, how can I update my web application without deleting those uploaded files?
Or maybe I was using the wrong approach with my application?

Comment: Where do you store the uploaded files?

Comment: You should not mix user data and the deployed application. put it into a database or outside of the application

Comment: Does this https://coderanch.com/t/559099/redeploy-webapp-exists help? Or that? https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-reload ? And how much prior research did you try on your own?

Comment: Besides: Jens is fully correct. Your WAR is about your application. That should not **at all** have anything to do with where your user data goes!

Comment: So, where should I put those uploaded files physically? any link for best practice?

Answer (score 0):

Since I need a quick fix. Here is what I did to make it work:

1. Create a temporary folder anywhere on the server lets say "/var/tmp/war_images". This will be used to temporarily store uploaded images when deploying a new war
2. Create a folder to put new WAR file. lets say "/var/tmp/war"
3. Create a shell script that do these things:

   - Copy all images from folder where user upload their images to the temp folder above
   - Delete application folder in tomcat
   - Delete WAR file in tomcat
   - Copy new WAR file from point 2 to tomcat8 folder
   - Restart tomcat (to trigger the deployment)
   - Copy back all images from point no.1 back to app folder newly created by the deployment process

So when I want to deploy a new WAR. I put the new WAR file on step no.2 and then execute the shell script.